# Url Rewriting in Yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

This is my current URL `https://localhost.com/vmmembers/view?name=aman`

I want this `https://localhost.com/window/aman`

I tried this with following code, but it does not work:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'pattern' => 'signup',
            'route' => 'site/signup'
        ],
        [
            'pattern' => 'about',
            'route' => 'site/about'
        ],
       'file/files/<file>' => 'file/files',
       '<action:policy|terms>' => 'site/<action>',
       '<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<title>' => '<controller>/view',
       '<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
       '<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<action:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<title>' => '<controller>/<action>',
       '<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<action:[A-Za-z-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
       '<controller:[A-Za-z-]+>/<action:[A-Za-z-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

        'vmmembers/<name:\d+>' => 'window/view',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this rule at the beginning of your rules list:

```
'window/<name:\w+>' => 'vmmembers/view',
```

Comment: Not Worked, Throwing 404 Error

Comment: It is hard to guess what is the source of this error without access to your controller code.

Comment: Controller Name is  **vmmembers**

action code is 

 public function actionWindow($type=null,$slug)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($slug),
        ]);
    }

Comment: Then it probably should be `'window/<slug:\w+>' => 'vmmembers/view',`/. You should update your question and give more details.

Comment: what else you wanted to know .?